# emberjs custom serialized field persisting differently

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following serializer:

import DS from 'ember-data';

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serialize: function(record, options) {
    var json = this._super(record, options);
    json.is_foo = true;
    return json;
  }
});
```

The idea is that I pass 'is_foo' back to the server. However, when I look at the payload the key has changed from `is_foo` to `is foo`. I'm not sure why this is. I've tried a number of variations, but can't get it to work. Is this the expected result or is there a bug somewhere in ember data?